# How to make pure CSS parallax code work with complex site?

Tags: html, css, background, styles, parallax

I'm trying to apply a complex parallax effect to my site. The background image should be behind the overall content and should move slower than the main content. I tried many approaches to this functionality but neither work.

So, according to what I understand, I need to first create a parallax wrapper.

```
    .parallax-wrapper {
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        perspective: 10px;
    }
```

This wrapper has a perspective, it hides the x overflow and sets the height of the overall content. It will be set just after the body tag.
Then, I have a section that should have a background that is a direct child of parallax-wrapper:

```
    .latest_news_section {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 390px;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

This section just formats the content and gives shape to it.
Then, I apply the shift of the Z plane to make sure the content is behind and it has a slower scroll:

```
    .latest_news_section::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        transform-origin: center;
        background-image: url("../img/top-back.jpeg");
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(2);
    }
```

However, the parallax starts working only when I disable `overflow: hidden;` from the section. And I don't know why. However, my colleague tested the same code and it worked.

Please check my version below:

HTML:

```css
.parallax-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.latest_news_section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 390px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.latest_news_section::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: center;
  background-image: url("https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/size/w2000/2021/06/w-qjCHPZbeXCQ-unsplash.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s;
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(2);
  transform-style: inherit;
}
.latest_news_section_header {
  font-family: AdobeInvisFont, OpenSans, Courier;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  font-family: AdobeInvisFont, Courier, OpenSans-Semibold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  width: 170px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green {
  background-color: #89ca62;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #14b9d5;
}

.some-content-to-fill {
  height: 1000px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax-wrapper">
    <div class="latest_news_section">
      <h1 class=".latest_news_section_header">
        THE LATEST NEWS ON DESIGN & ARCHITECTURE
      </h1>
      <div class="heading-buttons container">
        <button class="green">Subscribe Now</button>
        <button class="blue">Best Articles</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="some-content-to-fill">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur nisi temporibus debitis deleniti velit suscipit est aliquid voluptates voluptatem, consequatur ratione, minima autem ex inventore reiciendis commodi, harum repellendus nam! Cupiditate,
      amet expedita! Est beatae ut illum voluptatum quod nesciunt, similique minus labore consequuntur, nostrum ad ducimus libero eveniet aperiam recusandae, dignissimos totam quas ipsum explicabo! Dolore cupiditate expedita quisquam quis doloribus dolorum
      laborum ad excepturi odit cumque praesentium, quasi neque quia totam ea officia quibusdam nostrum, libero, eaque atque!
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you. I am trying to get this for a too long time and I don't have a single clue why it doesn't work without `overflow: hidden` disabled. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling is disabled when using `overflow: hidden;`
You need to do:

```css
.parallax-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
```